# Python: Make new tuple by attaching info from existing list

Tags: python, algorithm

I have 2 lists:

```
l = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
f = [[3,'Red'],[2,'Blue']]
```

I want to do with `l` based on `f` so the result will be something like:

```
result = ((1,'Red'), (2,'Red'), (3,'Red'), (4,'Blue'), (5,'Blue'), (6,'None'), (7,'None'))
```

Could you give me some code to do this simple and easy?
Thanks for any help!

Comment: you shouldn't name your variables as builtin python like `list`, it is a common source of errors (not in your case)

Comment: This is quite a trivial problem. What have you tried and where exactly are you stuck?

Comment: I'm using many `for` loops. I'm finding new simple solution. It may be trivial with some but serious with each others :). Anyway thanks!

Comment: If you already have done some work then you should show it, even if you feel it's not very good. We do usually prefer to see that you've applied some effort towards solving it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
result = tuple(itertools.izip_longest(l, (x[1] for x in f for y in range(x[0])), fillvalue='None'))
```